# O que é livelock?

Tags: terminologia, concorrência, livelock

O termo deadlock é bem conhecido na programação concorrente, porém acabei me deparando com o termo livelock nos meus estudos, e me perguntei o que seria isso?

O que é livelock? E poderia dar algum exemplo (com código em qualquer linguagem, ou pseudocódigo) de como isso acontece?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo, tradução livre, esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155951/whats-the-difference-between-deadlock-and-livelock):

Retirado de http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock :

> Na computação simultânea, um impasse é um estado no qual cada membro
>   de um grupo de ações está aguardando que outro membro libere um
>   bloqueio
>
> Um **livelock** é semelhante a um impasse, exceto que os estados dos
>   processos envolvidos no livelock mudam constantemente um em relação ao
>   outro, nenhum progredindo. Livelock é um caso especial de inanição de
>   recursos; a definição geral afirma apenas que um processo específico
>   não está progredindo.
>
> Um exemplo real de **livelock** ocorre quando duas pessoas se encontram em
>   um corredor estreito, e cada uma tenta ser educada movendo-se para o
>   lado para deixar o outro passar, mas elas acabam balançando de um lado
>   para o outro sem progredir, porque ambas se movem repetidamente da
>   mesma maneira ao mesmo tempo.
>
> **Livelock** é um risco em alguns algoritmos que detectam e se recuperam
>   de um conflito. Se mais de um processo executar uma ação, o algoritmo
>   de detecção de deadlock poderá ser acionado repetidamente. Isso pode
>   ser evitado, garantindo que apenas um processo (escolhido
>   aleatoriamente ou por prioridade) tome medidas.

Um exemplo para explicar um livelock pode ser encontrado neste [link](http://www.inf.ufsc.br/~bosco.sobral/ensino/ine5645/Prova%201-17052011_DOC_com%20respostas.pdf):

> Imagine um exemplo em que duas ou mais threads precisam adquirir todas
>   as Locks de um objeto, se a thread não conseguir obter todas as locks
>   então ela tenta de novo, isso cria um  livelock com todas as threads
>   tentando obter todos os locks mas nenhuma consegue porque uma
>   atrapalha a outra.
>
> LiveLock pode ocorrer numa situação onde há um
>   mecanismo de travas em um dado programa que tenham dos recursos
>   compartilhados, A e B. Se uma thread T1 requer lock sobre A e um T2
>   requer lock sobre B simultaneamente. Após isso T1 tenta acessar B e T2
>   tenta acessar A concomitantemente, T1 e T2 vão para um estado sleep,
>   quando acordam, voltam a buscar pelo recurso alvo, que continuará com
>   lock em ambas situações. Dada situação está constituído um livelock .

Um exemplo em Java pode ser extraído da [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8863671/10301489) desta pergunta [Good example of livelock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036364/good-example-of-livelock): (Recomendo a leitura dos comentários da resposta)

```java
public class Livelock {
    static class Colher {
        private Cliente dono;
        public Colher(Cliente c) { dono = c; }
        public Cliente getDono() { return dono; }
        public synchronized void setDono(Cliente c) { dono = c; }
        public synchronized void usar() { 
            System.out.printf("%s comeu!", dono.nome); 
        }
    }

    static class Cliente {
        private String nome;
        private boolean comFome;

        public Cliente(String n) { nome = n; comFome = true; }      
        public String getNome() { return nome; }
        public boolean isComFome() { return comFome; }

        public void comerCom(Colher colher, Cliente conjuge) {
            while (comFome) {
                // Não tem a colher, então espera pacientemente pelo conjuge.
                if (colher.dono != this) {
                    try { Thread.sleep(1); } 
                    catch(InterruptedException e) { continue; }
                    continue;
                }                       

                // Se o conjuge está com fome, insista em passar a colher.
                if (conjuge.isComFome()) {                  
                    System.out.printf(
                        "%s: Você come primeiro %s!%n", 
                        nome, conjuge.getNome());
                    colher.setDono(conjuge);
                    continue;
                }

                // Conjuge não está com fome, então coma usando a colher.
                colher.usar();
                comFome = false;                
                System.out.printf(
                    "%s: Estou cheio, %s!%n", 
                    nome, conjuge.getNome());               
                colher.setDono(conjuge);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Cliente marido = new Cliente("Bob");
        final Cliente esposa = new Cliente("Alice");

        final Colher colher = new Colher(marido);

        new Thread(() -> marido.comerCom(colher, esposa)).start();

        new Thread(() -> esposa.comerCom(colher, marido)).start();
    }
}
```