# O que é consistência eventual?

Tags: banco-de-dados, terminologia, arquitetura-de-software, ciência-da-computação

O termo tem sido usado cada vez mais no setor, especialmente em bancos de dados. O que ele quer dizer? Como funciona? Quais as vantagens e desvantagens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Eventual" significa que é dependente de acontecimento incerto, casual, fortuito.

"Consistência" vem de algo forte, estável, duradouro.

Então o termo é pomposo para indicar que algo que precisa ser forte, estável e duradouro, o será em algum momento, mas por enquanto ele é incerto, é fraco, instável e pode não durar. Ele promete que alcançará o objetivo, mas tudo pode acontecer no meio tempo.

Se você aceita que algo seja inconsistente para lidar com seu problema, ele pode ser uma solução em alguns casos. Se depende da consistência real, ou seja, firme e forte, não pode usar esta técnica.

Ela costuma ser usada em bancos de dados, mas pode ser aplicada em quaisquer mecanismos de software, especialmente se tiver alguma distribuição de processamento, então vale para microsserviços e outros mecanismos de distribuição. O banco de dados, se distribuído, é só um desses mecanismos.

É fácil perceber como ocorre em um banco de dados distribuído. Onde o mesmo dado, ou dados que sejam relacionados entre si, estão em mais de um local, provavelmente servidores físicos, e quando for acessar esses dados, eles podem estar em estados diferentes, de forma que não produza um resultado correto durante essa transição.

O resultado sempre será correto se não estiver ocorrendo uma modificação nos dados específicos que está trabalhando. E ele será correto em algum momento que toda a modificação for concluída. Então começa fazer a modificação em um servidor e depois faz em outros, sem muita preocupação quando os outros vão concluir essa modificação. Assim se você acessar um dado em um servidor, pode não ser o mesmo dado em outro. Ou pode acessar parte do dado em um estado, e outra parte dele que está em outro servidor não foi modificado para ficar consistente com o que já foi modificado na outra parte.

Exatamente como estará no fim do processo, ou até mesmo se a modificação será concluída, não é algo que possa determinar enquanto ele está acontecendo.

Para sistemas simples, não distribuídos, não tem porque usar isso, ainda que possa. Apenas quando se fala em particionamento é que pode haver essa necessidade. O **particionamento** só é necessário em volumes brutais de dados e acesso. A maioria dos problemas não são assim, até mesmo em volumes de internet a necessidade é mais rara do que parece (este site, um dos 50 mais acessados do mundo em certos momentos, não precisa).

Sem o particionamento a consistência é simples e não causa outros problemas.

Se realmente precisar do particionamento, talvez a técnica que deve acompanhar é o da indisponibilidade. Ou seja, você garante a consistência real, firme e forte. Um dado começa a ser modificado em um nó da distribuição, e não pode ser acessado em lugar algum até concluir todo o processo e garantir a consistência. Então o dado fica indisponível por um tempo até a **consistência** ser garantida.

A consistência é necessária, ou pelo menos desejável, na maioria dos problemas. O exemplo clássico é a conta bancária. Imagina quantos golpes podem ser dados quando o saldo bancário fica inconsistente por um tempo. O mesmo vale para estoque, ou algo que existe fisicamente no mundo de alguma forma, mas também pode ser algo só virtual que não pode ter seu estado parcial acessado. Com a consistência real você garante que toda modificação ocorra em determinada ordem, uma após a outra, e que ninguém vê o dado sendo modificado pela metade.

Qual é o problema disso e que a consistência eventual resolve?

Em alguns casos a falta de **disponibilidade** pode ser um problema, pode demorar muito, pode até mesmo ficar indisponível por tempo demais através de um ataque. Em alguns casos, boa parte deles, por erro na arquitetura, pode se tornar um tempo longo demais e tornar todo o sistema ineficiente e até criar um [*deadlock*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/64484/101) ou [*livelock*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/421381/101).

Muitos problemas lidam com dados triviais, que podem ser acessados sem problemas. O Facebook e outras plataformas assim usam muito isso. Eles possuem volumes gigantescos, que exigem particionamento. Podem ocorrer muitas modificações vindas de todos os lados, e não podem ficar esperando estarem disponíveis. Mas essas modificações podem ocorrer em qualquer ordem, pode não ter uma conclusão, pode uma pessoa ver e outra não, que não causa problema real algum para ninguém. Este é um caso que a consistência eventual brilha.

Ele só tem desvantagens se você não precisa de particionamento e disponibilidade ao mesmo tempo, porque segundo o [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem), que não é uma regra boba inventada por alguém, é matemática/física, não pode ter os três ao mesmo tempo. E se precisar dos três ao mesmo tempo, está lascado, você tem um problema insolúvel. A vantagem dele é justamente permitir esses dois funcionarem juntos, abrindo mão da consistência.

O termo foi criado para passar uma impressão de que a consistência existe, e é até verdade, mas ele minimiza a ideia que não tem consistência alguma, que nunca ficará consistente, o que provavelmente será inútil para todos os problemas.

Obter a consistência eventual pode ser bem difícil, mas claro que algumas ferramentas podem fazer isso por você. Mas nem todos os problemas podem ser resolvidos de forma tão automática.

Distribuição é considerado o problema mais difícil da computação, e manter a consistência, mesmo que eventual, pode ser tão difícil quanto.

A propagação para vários servidores pode criar algum impasse ou algo que torne inconsistente definitivamente, a não ser que encerre voltando ao estado original sem concluir o que foi pedido. E aí entra outro problema, porque é possível que alguém tenha sido notificado que concluiu, já que a disponibilidade exige isso.

Para minimizar isso, é comum que abra mão da disponibilidade por um tempo mais curto para pelo menos ter mais de um nó consistente. As técnicas exatas dependem do tipo de problema e necessidade que está lidando.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).